# Column 'country_id' does not belong to table . - Error Type : System.Data.DataColumn GetDataColumn(System.String)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, c#-4.0

Getting this error randomly only on server error log, actually the procedure GetAllCountries always return all countries and there is no chance of a result without country_id

I was logged the response DataTable to a file and the interesting this is that the logged response was returned by another stored procedure called from other function.
I think the DBHelper class shared the both responses or sql execute wrong procedure.

```
public List<Country> GetAllCountry()
    {
        List<Country> countries = new List<Country>();

        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "GetAllCountries";
            dt = DBHelper.Read(cmd);

            if (dt != null)
            {
                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    Country country = new Country();
                    country.CountryId = Convert.ToInt32(dr["country_id"]);
                    country.CountryCode =Convert.ToString(dr["country_code"]);
                    country.CountryName =Convert.ToString(dr["country_name"]);

                    countries.Add(country);
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            SysError.LogError(ex, "", "country", "GetAllCountry");
        }

        return countries;
    }

Read Function

public static class DBHelper
{

     private static string ConnStr;
                private static string Connection= "SettingsDB";
         public static DataTable Read(SqlCommand cmd)
                {

                    ConnStr = 
          ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[Connection].ConnectionString;
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnStr))
                        try
                        {

                            using (SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                            {
                                cmd.Connection = con;
                                con.Open();
                                dt.Locale = 
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
                                adp.Fill(dt);
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                             SysError.LogError(ex, "Read", "", "");
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            con.Close();
                        }

                    return dt;
                }
}
```

Stored Procedure in question:

```
select country_id ,
country_code ,
country_name +' '+'('+country_code+')' as country_name
from tbl_country 
order by country_name asc
```

Comment: What does your sql table/ stored procedure return look like?

Comment: @JamesS note this point :I was logged the response DataTable to a file and the interesting this is that the logged response was returned by another stored procedure called from other function.

Comment: ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].GetAllCountries 

AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    select 
     country_id
    ,country_code
    ,country_name +' '+'('+country_code+')' as countryname
     from tbl_country order by country_name asc
END

Comment: Without seeing the table structure of `tbl_country` OR what is being returned from the stored proc, my guess is one of two things. The column ID is either wrong in incorrectly cased. The other is that in one or more instances, `country_id` is null and so it cannot map it to an `int`

Comment: Confirm that country id is not null in one of the records

Comment: this error is happening randomly on server only, there is no chance for country id to be null. The sane thing happens for other stored procedures also.

Comment: It happens for other stored procedures that call this table?

Comment: in case of error the response in DataTable belongs to another stored procedure,

Comment: @JamesS No, for for other table also, so that i logged the DataTable data with error log.

Comment: Is there any chance of data sharing among different procedures calling from same function.

Comment: If what your stored proc is doing exactly and only what you have said. It should be returning the information from the table, regardless of what anything else does. Are you sure the database the servers are looking at is the same database you are debugging this against?

Comment: In the code you look for a column `"country_name"`. C#: `Country.CountryName =Convert.ToString(dr["country_name"]);` but in your stored procedure it is named "countryname" without underscore. SQL: `select country_id ,country_code ,country_name +' '+'('+country_code+')' as countryname from tbl_country`

Comment: @mortb I thought that as well but OP said that this is also happening to other stored procs that are calling other tables as well.

Comment: @JamesS yes you are right.

Comment: I'm looking for the  chance of data sharing among different procedures calling from same function.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible your issue is here?

```
                    Country country = new Country();
                    Country.CountryId = Convert.ToInt32(dr["country_id"]);
                    Country.CountryCode =Convert.ToString(dr["country_code"]);
                    Country.CountryName =Convert.ToString(dr["country_name"]);

                    countries.Add(country);
```

You instantiate a new instance of the class Country with the name country (lower case); however the assignments (Proper Case) are all for the class name dot (Country.) and not the instantiated name.  You then add the instantiated class to the list.  Also I agree with @mortb about `(dr["country_name"])`.

Comment: Thats just  a copy paste error, i was updated the question, there is no build or runtime error, this happens randomly on server.